# How to use more subprocesses when running tests in testthat?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, testthat

In a package, I have a dozen test files which run in parallel with `testthat` edition 3. By default, they run with 2 CPUs, and I would like to run them with more.

[The doc](https://testthat.r-lib.org/articles/parallel.html#basic-operation) says:

> Starting a new R process is relatively expensive, so `testthat` begins by creating a pool of workers. The size of the pool will be determined by `getOption("Ncpus")`, then the `TESTTHAT_CPUS` envvar. If neither are set, then two processes are started. In any case, `testthat` will never start more subprocesses than test files.

However, I don't understand *where* I should set the option so that my tests run on more than 2 CPUs (at least locally) when running tests from RStudio's "Build" pane.

I tried adding `Sys.setenv(TESTTHAT_NCPUS =4)` in my [testing helper file](https://testthat.r-lib.org/reference/test_file.html#special-files), but that didn't have any effect.

A [2020 github issue](https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/issues/1114) hints about a potential line in DESCRIPTION (`Config/testthat/ncpus`) but it doesn't seem it has been implemented.

How could I increase the number of CPU used for testing?

Comment: It sounds like you have one file with tests in it. Continuing the read from that webpage, *"testthat runs test **files** in parallel"*. (I assume you have added `Config/testthat/parallel: true` and `Config/testthat/edition: 3` to your `DESCRIPTION` file.)

Comment: @r2evans sorry that was not clear. I want to use more CPUs because I have multiple files that run in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

If your individual tests are running in serial, then it could be one of: edition not 3; `testthat/parallel` not set; perhaps something else with your tests that disable parallel execution.

Reproducible demonstration of `testthat` edition 3 running in parallel.

```r
devtools::create("somepkg") ; setwd("somepkg")
usethis::use_testthat(edition = 3)
Sys.getpid()
# [1] 16888
```

Edit `DESCRIPTION`, add the two `Config/*` lines, resulting in:

```
Package: somepkg
Title: What the Package Does (One Line, Title Case)
Version: 0.0.0.9000
Authors@R: 
    person("First", "Last", , "first.last@example.com", role = c("aut", "cre"),
           comment = c(ORCID = "YOUR-ORCID-ID"))
Description: What the package does (one paragraph).
License: `use_mit_license()`, `use_gpl3_license()` or friends to pick a
    license
Encoding: UTF-8
Roxygen: list(markdown = TRUE)
RoxygenNote: 7.2.3
Config/testthat/parallel: true
Config/testthat/edition: 3
```

I have no files in `./R/`. I added this to `tests/testthat.R`:

```r
library(testthat)
library(somepkg)
test_check("somepkg")
```

and these contents to four different files (`test1.R` through `test4.R`) within `tests/testthat/`:

```r
test_that("this will fail", {
  expect_equal(Sys.getpid(), 1)
})
```

(Yes, this is a stupid test, but since failures are clear in their failed expectations, this will report the actual PID in the summarized output.)

When I `devtools::test()` with no further changes, I see (among many lines removed):

```r
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Failure (test2.R:2): this will fail
Sys.getpid() (`actual`) not equal to 1 (`expected`).

  `actual`: 14584
`expected`:     1
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Failure (test1.R:2): this will fail
Sys.getpid() (`actual`) not equal to 1 (`expected`).

  `actual`: 5792
`expected`:    1
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Failure (test3.R:2): this will fail
Sys.getpid() (`actual`) not equal to 1 (`expected`).

  `actual`: 14584
`expected`:     1
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Failure (test4.R:2): this will fail
Sys.getpid() (`actual`) not equal to 1 (`expected`).

  `actual`: 5792
`expected`:    1
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

Since there are two PIDs listed (neither are `16888` from the parent process), this confirms that with no further action, 2 (separate) processes were used to run test files.

```r
Sys.setenv(TESTTHAT_CPUS=4)
devtools::test()
#   `actual`: 18692
#   `actual`: 3844
#   `actual`: 27160
#   `actual`: 9716
```

Unset that to make sure we're fully reset,

```r
Sys.setenv(TESTTHAT_CPUS="")
devtools::test()
#   `actual`: 30372
#   `actual`: 25928
#   `actual`: 30372
#   `actual`: 25928
```

Now using `options`:

```r
options(Ncpus=4)
devtools::test()
#   `actual`: 35012
#   `actual`: 33888
#   `actual`: 25208
#   `actual`: 19292
```

Comment: Thanks for this very thorough answer but the question was only about where I should put `Sys.setenv(TESTTHAT_CPUS=4)`.

Comment: Oooooh sorry I just figured out what was unclear. I'm working with RStudio and using the testing shortcut. Of course, if I run `devtools::test()` from the console it works, but I'd rather keep using the build pane so the environment is always clean.

Comment: Okay, got it ... so far I've tried various locations for `.Rprofile` and `.Renviron` (both in-package and global), no joy.

Comment: This question may need to be asked on the repo and/or of the devs; there is nothing clear in the docs, and there is only one place in the source (https://github.com/r-lib/testthat/blob/f8ccf033a74d89e2d1d3cb2ec3c6c4f63ca69055/R/parallel.R#L53) that appears to use this number.